# Microsoft Bot Framework identifying and greeting different users using request.user, but only getting last user who was added

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've deployed a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and Node.JS. I want to greet users who started a conversation with the bot based on identifying them by `request.user` param I send from template, the thing is, if two different users start the bot at the same time, the identification and greeting takes data only from the last one and show the same for both...

Here's the code:

Index.js

```
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();

const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const userState = new UserState(MemoryStorage);

const mybot = new MYBOT(conversationState, userState);

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
server.post('/direct_line/mybottoken', async function(req, res) {
        global.myuser = req.body.userName;  // I send the request.user from template
        global.greet = req.body.botGreet;   // And a custom greet for that specific user
        const result = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/tokens/generate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  process.env.DirectLineSecret,
            }
        });
        const token = await result.json();
        res.send(token);
});


server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
        adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        await mybot.run(context);
    });
});
```

And the method where I try my need on mybot.js:

```
        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const { channelId, membersAdded } = context.activity;
            if (channelId === 'directline' || channelId === 'webchat') {
              for (let member of membersAdded) {
                if (member.id === context.activity.recipient.id) {
                  if (myuser == 'Guest'){   // Here I ask if request.user saved on global myuser it's not logged
                      await context.sendActivity("Hi there guest !");
                  }else{
                      await context.sendActivity(greet); // Here I give the custom global greet for the logged user
                      var reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(['', '', '']);
                      await context.sendActivity(reply);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            await next();
        });
```

I know global vars are not the best approach, but I've been looking different solutions and always got the same result, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Is this for a Teams bot?

Comment: Nope, directline channel on webchat